# Start a new iteration of a loop from a different function in the loop [python]

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

How do you go about starting the next i without using continue or break?

```
def function_in_main():
    if #something happens:
        #start new next iteration for the loop in the main function

def main():
    n = 1
    for i in range(len(alist)): 
        print ('step ', n)

        function_in_main()

        n += 1
main()
```

Output should look somewhat like:

step 1

#if or until something happens

step 2

etc

Comment: Should the loop break if the condition `something happens` is not met?

Comment: @Hyperboreus no it shouldn't

Comment: Let me rephrase: What should happen if the condition `something happens` is not met?

Comment: Lol, this is a good question, but that depends on what you mean by good. I mean it is a bad question. There's so many different interpretations of what the intention could be and @chinex has not given any clues. It's a deviously ambiguous question. But at the end of the day, if you want to cease further processing of a loop iteration, and start the next iteration, that's what `continue` is for. That's why `continue` is in the language. Why would you not want to use `continue`? If not for the valiant attempts to answer this obscurity, I'd say delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just make function_in_main return when your if statement is true.  when it returns, the loop will move on to the next iteration and then re-call function_in_main.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
def function_in_main(x):
    return x=='Whopee'         # will return True if equal else False

def main():
    alist=['1','ready','Whopee']
    for i,item in enumerate(alist, 1): 
        print ('step {}, item: "{}" and {}'.format(i,item,function_in_main(item)))     

main()
```

Prints:

```
step 1, item: "1" and False
step 2, item: "ready" and False
step 3, item: "Whopee" and True
```

Note the use of [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) rather than manually keeping a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try raising an exception:

```
def function_in_main():
    if #something happens:
        raise Exception

def main():
    n = 1
    for i in range(len(alist)): 
        print ('step ', n)
        try:
            x()
        except Exception:
            continue

        n += 1
main()
```

You can specify or make whatever type of exception you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you're not thinking of a while loop or something? It's a little tough to see what you're getting at…

```
def your_function():
    #…do some work, do something to something else
    if something_is_true:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    condition = True
    for i in range(len(your_list)):
        while condition:
            print "Step: %d" % i
            your_function()
```

Only when `your_function` returns False will the loop in `main` continue, otherwise it will stay within the `while` loop.